# python типы данных

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, типы-данных

Есть набор данных типа object, если построить график по ним, то все получается нормально. Если поменять тип данных на float, то график совершенно не соответствует тому что при object. С чем это может быть связано? И как сделать так чтобы было и при float все корректно, так как для дальнейшей обработки нужны именно float. Заранее спасибо!

Данные загружаются из файла и создается DataFrame. Тип данных object.

```
Summary at time        GP

1005  3.0589000000000000e+04     65.22
1006  3.0619000000000000e+04  19391.91
1007  3.0650000000000000e+04     69.61
1008  3.0681000000000000e+04     59.79
1009  3.0710000000000000e+04     51.50
1010  3.0741000000000000e+04     47.63
1011  3.0771000000000000e+04   5821.52
1012  3.0802000000000000e+04   4659.31
1013  3.0832000000000000e+04   4056.77
1014  3.0863000000000000e+04   3649.93
1015  3.0894000000000000e+04   3357.23
1016  3.0924000000000000e+04   3121.40
1017  3.0955000000000000e+04   2923.38
1018  3.0985000000000000e+04   2764.70
1019  3.1016000000000000e+04   2620.68
1020  3.1047000000000000e+04   2498.85
1021  3.1075000000000000e+04   2390.34
1022  3.1106000000000000e+04   2288.30
1023  3.1136000000000000e+04   2191.79
1024  3.1167000000000000e+04   2105.11
1025  3.1197000000000000e+04   2024.18
1026  3.1228000000000000e+04   1946.56
1027  3.1259000000000000e+04   1880.71
1028  3.1289000000000000e+04   1812.01
1029  3.1320000000000000e+04   1748.42
1030  3.1350000000000000e+04   1691.69
1031  3.1381000000000000e+04   1644.56
1032  3.1412000000000000e+04   1598.90
1033  3.1440000000000000e+04   1564.24
1034  3.1471000000000000e+04   1519.17
```

При типе данных object ( x -time, y - GP)

[image]

При типе данных float ( x -time, y - GP)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Полный набор данных [cvs файл](https://%20dropmefiles.com/iwZDG)

Comment: без примера данных и кода для построения графика совершенно непонятно что вы пытаетесь сделать и что у вас не получается...

Comment: Сейчас добавлю.

Comment: а что говорит `df.dtypes`?

Comment: У DataFrame во всех столбцах object изначально. Если меня на float, пишет float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как раз с типом данных `float` - график получается нормальным:

```
In[22]: df
Out[22]: 
    Summary     time        GP
0      1005  30589.0     65.22
1      1006  30619.0  19391.91
2      1007  30650.0     69.61
3      1008  30681.0     59.79
4      1009  30710.0     51.50
..      ...      ...       ...
25     1030  31350.0   1691.69
26     1031  31381.0   1644.56
27     1032  31412.0   1598.90
28     1033  31440.0   1564.24
29     1034  31471.0   1519.17
[30 rows x 3 columns]

In[23]: df.plot.scatter(x='time', y='GP')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это только маленький кусок данных. На всех данных при float получается не правильно. Вот здесь все данные https://dropmefiles.com/iwZDG Буду очень благодарна, если посмотрите и подскажите что я делаю не так

Comment: @jokop, по-моему ваш второй график правильно отображает данные. Первый график не соответствует вашим данным.